# For loop only going through once

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, integer

Here is part of my code. At the part with the for loop: 
         I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is only looping though once. I have been staring at this for hours wondering why it only does this once. parse is equal to 3, so it should be doing it three times if my logic is correct.  Thanks.

```
public BigInt multiplcationHelper(BigInt B1,BigInt B2) {
    int size1 = this.num.size(), size2 = B2.num.size();// sizes of B1 and B2
    BigInt result = new BigInt();
    int parse = Integer.parseInt(B2.toString());
    int farse = Integer.parseInt(B1.toString());

    // result's num initial capacity of one more than B1's num and fill with null objects.
    result.num = new ArrayList (Collections.nCopies( size1+1, null ));

    //Both B1 and B2 are positive
    //if (B1.isPositive && B2.isPositive){ 
    for (int i = 0; i<parse; i++) {
        B1.add(B1);     
    //}
    }
    //result = B1;
    return B1;
}
```

Comment: You should print out the value of `parse` to be sure, or step through in a debugger.

Comment: Because `BigInt` is your own implementation, post the code just to be sure there's nothing in your methods `add` and `toString`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're confused by is that `B1.add(B1);` doesn't actually double `B1`. You probably want `B1 = B1.add(B1);`. As the API states at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html, `add()` just returns a new `BigInteger`; it doesn't affect the BigInteger that calls it.

Are you actually required to use BigInteger for this? A value of 3 should just be an `int` (BigInteger is serious overkill).

Comment: Yes, I am required to use BigInteger. I stepped through a debugger and parse is the correct number. Also, I have used B1 = B1.add(B1) but I get a number that is way to high.

Comment: It's definitely going to be very high. After making the slight change I suggested, the value of `B1` is going to double with each iteration of the loop (which is what I assumed you wanted). Are you just looking to create a function that returns the product of two BigInts? There's a *much* simpler way to do this: use `BigInteger.multiply()` (read about it at the API link).

Comment: I am looking to create a function that returns the product of two BigInts. I cannot use the Big Integer class, I had to make my own implementation of it. What I am attempting to do is use the addition method I have created as a multiplication method by looping through.

Comment: You're actually fairly close. First, get rid of all the variables in the function that you're not using: `size1`, `size2`, `result`, `farse`, and the line starting with `result.num =`. Next, go back to basics. If you wanted to multiply 5 x 6, another way to think of that is starting with 0, and continuously adding 5 to it 6 times. Your loop is sort of doing that, but start by creating a counter `BigInt` outside the loop initialized to 0. Increment the counter with each iteration. There's one other change you'll have to make to your existing loop; I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: I got rid of the variables and turned it into this: I'm still unsure why this does not work. I just cannot fathom why it is not adding B1 to 0 5 times like I want it to.   'BigInt counter = new BigInt("0");
  counter = B2;
  for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
  B2 = counter.add(B1);
  '

Comment: Before asking for a code review, test the code for yourself. When you input 4 and 6 to this function, are you getting 24? Probably not, because while this code is closer, I still see flaws with it. I'm not going to explicity list them for you, because you'll learn more by sweating through this problem yourself (don't take it personally- I used to teach middle school :) Pull out the debugger as you did before, input small integers like 4 and 6 to the function, and see what happens on each iteration of the loop. Here's one last hint: you're going to want to `return counter;` from your function.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this more and I am starting to think that this implementation is impossible for very large integers since the variable parse is going to be much higher than an int can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is

```
int size1 = this.num.size(), size2 = B2.num.size();// sizes of B1 and B2
```

But `size1` is not `B1` size. Try:

```
int size1 = B1.num.size(), size2 = B2.num.size();// sizes of B1 and B2
```